# Refund request permission denied in paypal rest API

Tags: paypal-sandbox, paypal-rest-sdk

i try make request to paypal in sandbox mode:

```
{
    "body": {
        "amount": {
            "currency": "USD",
            "total": 3.15
        }
    },
    "header": {
        // this my header
    },
    "additional_properties": {},
    "method": "POST"
}
```

Get response:

```
{
    "status": 401,
    "duration_time": 592,
    "body": {
        "message": "Permission denied.",
        "information_link": "https://developer.paypal.com/webapps/developer/docs/api/#PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "name": "PERMISSION_DENIED",
        "debug_id": "206feb0f3855f"
    },
    "additional_properties": {},
    "header": {
        "Date": "Wed, 19 Apr 2017 20:50:14 GMT",
        "paypal-debug-id": "206feb0f3855f",
        "APPLICATION_ID": "APP-80W284485P519543T",
        "Content-Language": "*",
        "CALLER_ACCT_NUM": "PBL6EFNEJZVTE"
    }
}
```

11 April this request worked. But today i get this error. Source code was not be changed. How fix it?

Answer (score 0):

It was be paypal bug. Today all work fine.